# I want to convert jpg image sequence in folder to mov by adding windows context menu for a folder

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, context-menu, jpeg, quicktime

I am using ffmpeg code to convert the available jpg sequence to mov(Photojpg)

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -r 24 -start_number 1001 -i /ip/Seq/image.%04d.jpg -y -xerror -vcodec copy -r 24 /ip/Seq/movie.mov
```

But every time I have to replace the input and output path and the crazy part is I have to do it for 100 of shots inside the production every day.

I want to create a windows context menu called "Convert to mov" for the folder. To convert the content 
of the folder(Jpeg sequence) to mov using ffmpeg on a windows machine.

After adding the context menu, I tried with the following bat script but I am converting one jpg to mov

Here is the bat file

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -r 24 -start_number 1001 -i "%~1" -y -xerror -vcodec copy -r 24 "%~dl\%~p1\%~n1.mov"
```

Below is the .reg script

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.jpg\shell\ConvertToMOV]
@="Convert to MOV"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.jpg\shell\ConvertToMOV\command]
@="\"C:\\ffmpeg\\convert_to_mov.bat\"\"%1\""
```

Many thanks in Advance

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I just want to right click on a folder to get windows context menu let say "Convert to mov" to convert the folder content(jpg sequence) to mov on windows 10.

Comment: Okay, have you already tried something? We expect users to ask a specific question that includes some research into what they have already done.

Comment: I used this bat script to convert jpg sequence into mov       ffmpeg -f image2 -r 24 -start_number 1001 -i "%~1" -y -xerror -vcodec copy -r 24 "%~dl\%~p1\%~n1.mov".

Comment: For windows context, I added a regedit file for the jpg file association using this scriptWindows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.jpg\shell\ConvertToMOV]
@="Convert to MOV"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.jpg\shell\ConvertToMOV\command]
@="\"C:\\ffmpeg\\convert_to_mov.bat\"\"%1\"" ... Using this I am able to convert a single jpg file to mov. but not the entire seq. I also tried of doing this with the directory but It didn't work.

Comment: In your batch file you have to loop over the folder's contents, or all passed file names, and inside that loop, run the FFmpeg command that you are already using.

Comment: It was creating mov for every jpg frame inside the folder. Could you help me with this

Comment: Please edit your question and show the full batch file you are currently using.